# How to set css variable in stenciljs shadow component via javascript

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, stenciljs

I have a shadow component in stenciljs like

```js
@Component({
    tag: "digital-verification",
    styleUrl: "digital-verification.scss",
    shadow: true,
})
```

and I have some css variable like

```
:host {
  --app-primary-color: #488aff;
  --app-border-radius: 10px;
  --app-error-color: #EE320C;
}
```

Till now everything is working perfect and no issue.

Now I want to set this variables in the code like

```
document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--app-primary-color', '#ffffff');
```

I tried

```
   document.querySelector(':host').style
```

and

```
document.querySelector(':root').style
```

and

```
document.querySelector(':root').shadowRoot.style
```

and

```
    document.querySelector(':root').root.style
```

and

```
@Element() el;

...
this.el.shadowRoot.querySelector(":host") // this is null
```

but I get compile error that `Element doesn't have style`

Wondering how should I see css variables in the code.

### update

I did below code, and I can see value is set in console, but application color doesn't change

```
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--app-primary-color", "#ff0000");
        console.log(document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue("--app-primary-color"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case somebody else has same issue

I did the below steps and issue is resolved

1- I deleted the below section

```
:host {
  --app-primary-color: #488aff;
  --app-border-radius: 10px;
  --app-error-color: #EE320C;
}
```

2- defined a variable like below

```
$primary-color : var(--app-primary-color, #488aff);
```

3- in code set the css variable like below

```
 document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--app-primary-color", "#ffff00" , "important");
```

### Updated solution based on @Danny '365CSI' Engelman comment

1- You can delete the below section if you want to variable be applied to all children or keep it if you want it to be applied only on this component

```
:host {
  --app-primary-color: #488aff;
  --app-border-radius: 10px;
  --app-error-color: #EE320C;
}
```

2- define `@Element() el: HTMLElement;` in your component

3- in code set the css variable like below

```
 this.el.style.setProperty("--app-primary-color", "#ffff00");
```

Comment: Works because you are now setting the property on the outermost element ``document``, so if anything else on the page uses ``--app-primary-color`` it changes as well. If you want it scoped to an Element, and set it from **within** the element use: ``this.style.setProperty()`` or ``this.shadowRoot.style.setProperty()`` depending if you wat to target your ``<digital-certification>`` element or its shadowRoot. From the **outside** it is: ``document.querySelector("digital-certification").style.setProperty()`` or ``document.querySelector("digital-certification").shadowRoot.style.setProperty()``

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman thanks, I tried, in the stencils component `shadowRoot` and `style` are not available on `this`, it's available on element `@Element() el: HTMLElement;`